# Dynamically loaded script with JS or JQ working only after refresh

Tags: javascript

I have little problem when I'm trying to load a script with JS or JQ.
I have added jquery of the bottom of the body and another script after it.
From this script I'm loading one more script but sometimes I need to refresh the page to make it to work.

I have tried with JS:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "scriptPath.js";
    script.async = false; // the result is same with true
    script.onload = function () {
      //do something here
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
 });
```

I have tried with JQ:

```
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $.getScript( "scriptPath.js" )
      .done(function() {
        //do something here
      })
      .fail(function() {
        //do something here
    });
  });
```

I also have tried to load the scripts in the head tag but result is the same.
Any suggestions what can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet which works..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        BOO
    </div>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "2.js";
            script.async = false; // the result is same with true
            script.onload = function () {
                console.log(booVar);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2.js content:

```
var booVar = 'booV';
```

Note,  section is at the end of the body in this case. If the same script is placed in 's  part, it wouldn't work because document.body would be null at that point.